# (need help)opening 2 iframes link in 1 click (PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

These are my iframes:

```
<div class="iframe"> 
    <iframe src="iframe1.html"  name="iframe_a">
    </iframe>
</div>

<div class="iframe2"> 
    <iframe src="iframe1.html" "name="iframe_a2">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

In HTML, with JavaScript, I'm using the following and it works:

```
<script>
function changeLink(link) {
   parent.iframe_a2.location=link;
}
</script>
```

HTML Code:

```
<li>
    <a href="select1.php" target="iframe_a" 
       onClick="changeLink('select2.php')">Home</a>
</li>
```

In PHP I have almost the same code but the `onclick` function is not running, only the

`<a href='select1.php?page=$i' target='iframe_a'` changed. Meaning there's nothing happen in my frame 2 -- `iframe_a2` (onclick).

Here is the code:

```
<script>
function changeLink(link) {
parent.iframe_a2.location=link;
}
</script>
```

PHP Code:

```
echo ("<a href='select1.php?page=$i' target='iframe_a' 
  onClick='changeLink('select2.php?page=$i)'>Home</a>");
```

Comment: `In PHP I have almost the same code but the onclick function is not running, only the` -- what exactly do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in this code:

```
echo ("<a href='select1.php?page=$i' target='iframe_a' onClick='changeLink('select2.php?page=$i)'>Home</a>")
```

Try this:

```
echo ("<a href='select1.php?page=$i' target='iframe_a' onClick=\"changeLink('select2.php?page=$i')\">Home</a>")
```